# Receiving a Http Post request on my server

Tags: asmx, webmethod, webhooks, trello

I am attempting to make an asmx file (written in c#) which will receive a POST request from another service, in this case Trello. However I believe I am having trouble receiving a 'JSON payload'. Trello is creating the request so I don't know exactly what their code looks like. The code I am using to recieve the request is of the form:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TrelloCallback()
{
    //connect to database
    //do stuff
    //return "OK"
}
```

However this fails immediately, even if my code only consists of "return OK". I have used Applications such as Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and have successfully sent both post and get request to TrelloCallback using the url excample.com/excample2.asmx/TrelloCallback, however requests from Trello simply fail.

If anyone has any idea about what could be causing this problem, or has solutions for a workaround I would be very grateful.

p.s.
The payload is of the form:

```
{
  action: { ...  }//Action (comment, move)
  model: { ... }//Basic information 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to make sure you have the line for ScriptService

```
namespace MyName
{
    ...
        [ScriptService]
    ...
    public class MyClass: MyWebService
    {
    ...
```

Then you only need to read through the stream to get the Body

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Context.Request.InputStream);
Context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
String Body= reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

Context.Request.XXX provides many useful messages for interoperating the request you received.

For example - Context.Request.Headers, Context.Request.RawUrl, and Context.Request.HttpMethod.

Comment: This is the method I've used with ASMX services.  It allows you to capture the posted XML/JSON data, and then you can attempt to use XmlSerializer to serialise the data into your object.